# titanium app.js getting overwritten when building

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium to create  a mobile app.

The problem I've having is that my entire Resources directory is getting overwritten each time I build my project.  Any reason why?  It makes it so I can't edit app.js (which is in that directory) to include my global functions file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the Alloy framework in Titanium. With Alloy you dont modify the app.js, it is autogenerated for you.  Modify the code, styles, and view files inside of the `app/` directory.

[Check here for more documentation about alloy.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework)

Comment: You're right, thanks.  Looks like I need to declare global vars and functions in alloy.js.

Comment: Yes, and index.js, thats your starting point as opposed to app.js.